$\sqrt{ab}\neq \big(\sqrt a\big)\big(\sqrt b\big)$ When Both $a$ & $b$ Are Negative: Direct Proof + Counterexample
Edit: There are many questions regarding this inequality like here, but this one is about proof-writing, not the theorem itself. I want to check whether this proof is correct and know how to improve its readability.
Define $i$ to be $\sqrt{-1}$ ; such that $(\forall x\geq 0) [\sqrt{-x}=i\sqrt x]$
We want to show the inequality:
$$(\forall a,b \geq 0)\bigg[(\sqrt{-a}) (\sqrt {-b}) =(i\sqrt{a}) .(i\sqrt{b}) \boldsymbol\neq\sqrt{abi^2}=\sqrt{-ab} \bigg]$$
Counterexample:

Suppose for any negative $a$ and $b$ we have: $(\sqrt a)(\sqrt
 b)=\sqrt{a.b}$
$$\mbox{So we can conclude:} \\2=1+1 \\
 =1+\sqrt1 \\=1+\sqrt{(-1)(-1)} \\ 
\stackrel{\small Assumption}{=}1+\large(\normalsize\sqrt{-1}\large)(\normalsize\sqrt{-1}\large)
 \\\rightarrow 2=1+i^2
=1+(-1)=0\\2=0 \ \\ \Rightarrow\!\Leftarrow $$

My question regarding this counterexample is that I think I have written too much, is that a problem? Could there be any adjustment which improves this proof on a technical level?
Direct Proof:

$$\big(\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}\big) \bigg[
 t:=(\sqrt{-|a|})(\sqrt{-|b|)}= (i\sqrt{|a|}).(i\sqrt{|b|})  \bigg]
 \mathbf{\small (\textrm{$t$ is obviously negative $\tiny(i^2=-1)$}})
 \\ \Rightarrow t^2=
 \bigg((i\sqrt{|a|}).\big(i\sqrt{|b|}\big)\bigg)\bigg(\big(i\sqrt{|a|}\big).(i\sqrt{|b|})\bigg)\\
 =i^4\bigg(\sqrt{|a|}\bigg)^2\bigg(\sqrt{|b|}\bigg)^2 \\
 =(-1)^2\bigg(\sqrt{|a.b|}\bigg)^2 \\=|a.b| \\ $$ Finally, we have: $$ |t|=-t=\sqrt{t^2}=\pm\sqrt{|a.b|} \\ $$ Since we know $t$ cannot have
a non-negative value, only $t=-\sqrt{|ab|}$ is acceptable. It's also
clear that: $$i\sqrt{ab} \neq -\sqrt{|ab|}$$

About the direct proof, I'm not really sure if it's complete. Should any alternations be made here as well?

How did you define the square root for complex numbers? Or did you only define $\sqrt{-a} = i\sqrt{a}$ for $a\geq 0$?

I defined $i:=\sqrt{-1}$
This results $\sqrt{-a}=\sqrt{(-1)(a)}= \sqrt{-1} \sqrt a$ for $a\geq0$
@rafilou2003

This $\sqrt{-a}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt a$ does not result from $i:=\sqrt{-1}$. Please edit your post to include your definition $\sqrt{-a}=i\sqrt a$ for $a\ge0$.

"Suppose for any negative a and b we have: (a−−√)(b√)=a.b−−−√"  Um.  You most certainly and famously do NOT have $\sqrt a\sqrt b = \sqrt ab$ if $a,b$ are both negative.  That's a very famous false proof.  $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{|ab|}=\sqrt{|a||b|}=\sqrt{|a|}\sqrt{|b|}$ whereas $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=i\sqrt{|a|}\cdot i\sqrt{|b|} = -\sqrt{|a|}\sqrt{|b|}$.

"$i\sqrt{ab} \neq -\sqrt{|ab|}$.  That's not true if either $a$ or $b$ is zero.

"grown-up" mathematician really are loath to define $i = \sqrt{-1}$ and for $x\in \mathbb R; x < 0$ to define $\sqrt{x}= i\sqrt{|x|}$.  There are many problems and pitfalls with this idea that have been much discussed elsewhere.

This question is similar to: Intuitive reason why $\sqrt a\cdot\sqrt b \neq \sqrt {ab}$ when $a$ and $b$ are negative. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@AnneBauval You're right. I didn't consider the equation $(\forall a \in \mathbb{R}) \sqrt -1 . \sqrt x = \sqrt{-x}$ can't be proven just by that definition. I'll edit the question.

@fleablood That was a counter example of why it doesn't work. The $\Rightarrow!\Leftarrow$ is supposed to show the contradiction it leads to.

Then you seem to be confusing "every" with "any".  You have demonstrated that $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\ne \sqrt{(-1)(-1)}$ but that only shows that $a=-1;b=-1$ doesn't work.  That means that it's not true for EVERY possible value; not that its not true for ANY value.... It's actually very hard to know what you are asking, trying to show, or what issue you think there is.

All in all, this is common naive question. In the end it is pointless to talk about the square root of a number as all non-zero numbers have two square roots and it is arbitrary which one we declare as more important than the other.  The important result is that if $w_a$ is a root of $a$ and $w_b$ is a root of $b$, then $w_aw_b$ is a root of $ab$. Alway. Now if you predetermine that the root of $ab$ you are interested in is $w_{ab}$ then maybe $w_aw_b=w_ab$ but maybe it is the other root (which is $-w_ab$). But always $(w_aw_b)^2=ab$. Always.

@fleablood Definitely. Up to this moment, I had thought "every" and "any" can be used alternatively. Thanks for correcting this.

"I don't have any cats" vs. "I don't have any cat".   "Oh, give her anything" vs. "Oh, give her everything".  Language can be ambiguous.  "Is that true for any number?". Usually means "Is that ever true/Is there a single case where it is true".  But it might be interpreted as "Is that true for any number that I pick?/Is it always true".  One has to be clear.

As it is written, your statement is obviously false. You must replace $(\forall a,b\ge0)$ by $(\forall a,b>0)$. Now, since it begins with $\forall$, your counterexample (besides being overcomplicated as commented) doesn't prove it. As for your (direct) proof, it can be shortened and should be corrected, as follows:
Define $$(\forall x\ge0)\quad\sqrt{-x}:=i\sqrt x.$$
Then,$$(\forall a,b>0)\quad\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b}=i^2\sqrt a\sqrt b=-\sqrt{ab}\ne i\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{-ab}.$$

Actually, with the counterexample, I wanted to prove $(\forall a,b<0)\sqrt a \sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$ is false, but forgot to write that down. But I guess I shouldn't edit the question to add that since it's a proof-check.
As for $\sqrt{-a}\sqrt{-b}=i^2\sqrt a=-\sqrt{ab}$, why not also omit the middle part $i^2\sqrt a \sqrt b$? How is that more necessary than those that have been removed in this shortened version?

@Karaji don't confuse "any" with "every".  And don't confused "not always true" with "always false".

Indeed: this was the part "since it [the statement] begins with ∀, your counterexample doesn't prove it" of my answer. As for the remaining steps in the shortened version, I found them necessary because they apply your definition of the square root of a negative number.

And... I think we need to keep in mind defining:  If $a > 0$ then $\sqrt{-a}:= i\sqrt{a}$ (as opposed to $-i\sqrt{a}$ which is also a square root of $a$), is an arbitrary choice.  It is a valid choice for a definition but there is nothing significant about it. And a not of mathematicians choose not to make such a choice and such a definition.
